# unable to save custom taxonomy terms in a custom-built metabox in wp-admin

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox, save-post

I have created two custom taxonomies i.e states and provinces but am unable to save the data in custom build meta boxes in wp-admin:

```
<?php function custom_meta_box() {

    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-states', 'post', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-provinces', 'post', 'side' );

    add_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-states', 'US States', 'states_meta_box', 'post', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-provinces', 'Canada Provinces', 'provinces_meta_box', 'post', 'side' );

}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'custom_meta_box');

/* Prints the taxonomy box content */
function states_meta_box($post) {

    $tax_name = 'states';
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($tax_name);
?>
<div class="tagsdiv" id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>">
    <div class="jaxtag">
    <?php 
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'states_noncename' );
    $states_IDs = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'states', array('fields' => 'ids') );
    wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=states&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&name=states&show_option_none=Select US State&selected='.$states_IDs[0]); ?>
    <p class="howto">Select US State</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom taxonomy */
function states_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) || wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) 
      return;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['states_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      return;


  // Check permissions
  if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

  $states_ID = $_POST['states'];

  $states = ( $states_ID > 0 ) ? get_term( $states_ID, 'states' )->slug : NULL;

  wp_set_object_terms(  $post_id , $states, 'states' );

}
/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'states_save_postdata' );


/* Prints the taxonomy box content */
function provinces_meta_box($post) {

    $tax_name = 'provinces';
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($tax_name);
?>
<div class="tagsdiv" id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>">
    <div class="jaxtag">
    <?php 
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'provinces_noncename' );
    $provinces_IDs = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'provinces', array('fields' => 'ids') );
    wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=provinces&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&name=provinces&show_option_none=Select Province&selected='.$provinces_IDs[0]); ?>
    <p class="howto">Select Canadian Province</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom taxonomy */
function provinces_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) || wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) 
      return;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['provinces_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      return;


  // Check permissions
  if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

  $provinces_ID = $_POST['provinces'];

  $provinces = ( $provinces_ID > 0 ) ? get_term( $provinces_ID, 'provinces' )->slug : NULL;

   wp_set_post_terms(  $post_id , $provinces, 'provinces' );

}
/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'provinces_save_postdata' );?>
```

Comment: If you remove all the authentication do they save?

Comment: @Anthony, could you edit your question / accept the edits - the formatting of the code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than 'returning' on a failure of authentication check, die with an appropriate message:

For example:

```
  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['states_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      wp_die("Nonce-check failure");
```

This will indicate on what check (if any) that you are failing. In most cases, I would advise **doing this rather than returning as it gives the user feedback.** Obviously, you should not do this for the 'auto-save' check - but otherwise, if its clear there is desire to do something, but they are not allowed to, an error message would be preferable to a silent fail.

I think, though that the error lies in the permissions check:

```
  // Check permissions
  if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }
```

You check that the post is a post (rather than CPT/page) but then you check if the current user can edit this **page**. This is likely to return false, because the `$post_id` refers to a post not a page.

Try swapping the `!current_user_can`s around. As I mentioned above, the 'die' messages should help you debug this.

Finally, and though not related to your problem, you should **make sure your functions do not have generatic names**: `custom_meta_box` - you should always prefix them with something unique. If this isn't something for general release, you might be ok, but it's just good practise.